# Referring to an external html code fragment

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using flask 1.1.2. Everything is working fine.

This is my basic layout.html

### layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">    

            <!-- a great big chunk of bootstrap html for the nav bar>

        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {% block body %} 
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a bunch of html files to fill in the body template:

### body1.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 
{% block body %} 
<div>
<!-- a bunch of stuff>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my app.py I have things like this:

### app.py

```
@app.route('/body1')
def body1():
    return render_template('body1.html')
```

This all works.

How can I move `<!-- a great big chunk of bootstrap html for the nav bar>` into an external file? This nav code never changes and I just want to refer to it externally to simplify my `layout.html`

Because my routing in flask refers to the "body" file which gets applied to layout.html. How do I make layout.html always get the nav code from an external file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `{% include 'external.html' %}`. See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#include